# Xunit and EFCore - Mocking One-To-Many relationship does not work

Tags: c#, mocking, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, xunit

## Intro

I have problems mocking the database for my one-to-many relationship between a user and the employments. The employment is added correctly to the mock database, but when the same entity is added to an Collection of Employments in the User entity, it does not load.

## Code

These are just the important parts for this case of the two classes

#### User

```cs
public virtual ICollection<Employement> Employments { get; } = new List<Employment>();
```

#### Employment

```cs
[Required]
[ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public virtual User? User { get; set; }
```

## Example

I use something called `EntityHelper` to create the entities. I create the employment entity, use it when I create the User entity (these are all created correctly when I debug). I use `db.AddRange()` to add the entities to the database.

Here is how that looks.

[image]

## The problem

As I mentioned earlier, almost everything is added correctly to the database. The user with its data, and the employment. The collection of employments in the user is however empty (even though the user entity I created have it). I'm not sure if this is a problem with EF Core or XUnit or what it might be.

Some other facts that might be good to know:

- The test uses an SqLite in-memory database
- It is based on a DbContext

Comment: Hi Anton, since you are using an in-memory database over the database context, this seems to be more like an integration test, and integration tests normally don't ```mock``` anything, in the sense that you would like to test the concrete implementation of your code. Can you provide the error message that you receive, along an image of the debugger when it throws (I suspect) an exception?. If you stop the debugger, evaluate ```DbContext.User.ToList()``` you get what you would expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a missing `.include(u => u.Employments)` in the LINQ query that fetched the users from the database.